# Phonegap not working in Android emulator

Tags: android, cordova

I followed all the steps in the basic Phonegap tutorial (Eclipse, Android SDK, ADT Phonegap), I created an HMTL page in the assets/www folder, ran it, and it showed my `hello world html`.

Step 2: I added a reference to jQuery Mobile on a CDN in my HTML page: it worked.

Step 3: I created a new html page, copy-pasted the code below, which is a sample from the Phonegap site, and it does... nothing. Not even an alert (I added some alerts to see if something happens, but even the onDeviceReady event doesn't fire.

I have the Phonegap JAR in place, the `cordova-1.7.0.js` in my `assest/www` directory, but something is probably missing.

Can someone help me out?

I also tried another sample from the Phonegap site (the 'device properties' sample), but it still doesn't work.

It's a fresh Eclipse install, I've set the Android version to 2.3.3 and I'm using Phonegap 1.7.0.

================

## EDIT

I tried some more, and I now can reproduce the error, but don't know why it happens.

So I created a new project with the Phonegap example project, it works.

So, I copied all the assets from that project (1 html, 2 js and 1 css) to my projects, let the app start with that html (from my activity class), and it works.

And now for the fun part (not): I reset the startpage to my 'old' index.html (which is jQuery mobile), and then clicked on a link to the example html, it does NOT work.

So example html as startup: it works, example html opened via the link: does NOT work.

And when I loaded my other html pages which didn't work as start page, instead of opening them via the start page, they work too.

So, is it possible that my jQuery Mobile-powered index page causes trouble ? (I'll copy-paste the code below).

EDIT2: When I use a non-jQuery Mobile index page and I link with a normal `<A href>` link to the example html, it also works. So that's hinting more and more to the fact that I think jQuery mobile is in my way...

The link code is this:

```
<li><a href="index4.html" data-transition="none">phonegap example</a></li>
```

The jQuery Mobile home page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.verfrisser.net/kalender/mobile/verfrisser.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>De NerdNight kalender</h1>
        <a href="about.html" data-rel="dialog">About</a><a href="genereren.html" data-transition="pop">Genereren</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <img id="verfrisserlogo" src="verfrisserlogo.png" />
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false">
            <li><a href="2011.html" data-transition="none">2011</a></li>
            <li><a href="2012.html" data-transition="none">2012</a></li>
            <li><a href="2013.html" data-transition="none">2013</a></li>
            <li><a href="testing.html" data-transition="none">testing</a></li>
            <li><a href="testing2.html" data-transition="none">testing2</a></li>
            <li><a href="testing3.html" data-transition="none">testing3</a></li>
            <li><a href="index4.html" data-transition="none">phonegap example</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h6>(C) Verfrisser 1998 till now</h6>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

================

The sample HTML (which only shows the text 'A dialog box will report the network state' in the page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>    
    <title>navigator.network.connection.type Example</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    
   // Wait for Cordova to load    //    
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);  
   // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods   
    alert ('stand alone');
   //    
   function onDeviceReady() {
    alert ('onDeviceReady'); 
   checkConnection();   
   }    
   function checkConnection() {        
   var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;        
   var states = {};       
   states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';        
   states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';        
   states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';       
   states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';   
   states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';   
   states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';   
   states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
   alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]); 
   }  

</script> 
</head>  
<body>
    <p>A dialog box will report the network state.</p>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you added the Android Permission? have you added cordova.xml and plugins.xml in res?

Comment: Yeah, the permissions are in place. The 2 xml files i'm not sure i've read about them in my tutorial. Can you point me in the right direction about them?

Comment: In your application res folder you need to add the xml folder which is present in the lib folder of the downloaded phonegap package. This xml folder contains both the xmls

Comment: Allright, i'll give that a try

Comment: Do let me know if it works. Else we will try something new :)

Comment: Checked it, and at my \phonegap.helloworld\res\xml folder where both files...

Comment: I found the trouble, at least i think. I've edited the question. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: is it possible that you put all the html files somewhere (best gist.github.com) so we can test them in local setup??

Comment: @dhaval sources are here: https://gist.github.com/2938275 (i added the index.html (startup page), testing2.html (one of the pages that is not working). I added the cordovaa.js also, but that one is a default install one (at least it should be)

Comment: try with this code `<li><a href="testing2.html" data-transition="none" rel="external">testing2</a></li>`, runs all the alert when i move to `testing2.html` with it

Comment: @dhaval two questions: 1.why should that work, and 2. can you post that as an answer?

Comment: I'll keep it a surprise for now, but question 2 gives a hint :-)

Comment: ok i am putting the answer with explanation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With default behavior the next page will be loaded as a DOM element so the javascript `deviceready` will not be called again.

Try with one of these ways to run it the normal way:

```
<li><a href="testing2.html" data-transition="none" rel="external">testing2</a></li>
```

Or

```
<li><a href="testing2.html" data-transition="none" data-ajax="false">testing2</a></li>
```

Explanation:

> When a link is clicked, jQuery mobile will make sure the link is
> referencing a local URL, and if so, it'll prevent the link's default
> click behavior from occurring and request the referenced url via Ajax
> instead. When the page returns successfully, it will set the
> location.hash to the new page's relative url.
>
> If the Ajax request is successful, the new  page content is added to the DOM, all mobile widgets are auto-initialized, then the new  page is animated into view with a page transition.

For more detail info check the [doc](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)

Comment: Y.O.U. R.O.C.K. I've been fighting this issue at least 30 minutes every day for the last week, trying all kinds of things, and disappointed every time. You can imagine the smile on my face when this answer did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

As far as no bug in your code. This above code structure is not well constructed. You mentioned the phonegap and jquery mobile javascript in the head of first page and not in the second page. It does not have any jquery mobile javascript file in the head.

Facts from my knowledge :

- You can do Jquery transition from one jquery mobile page to another
  jquery mobile included page.
- Include the standard library files in the both header.

This will do your job.

Comment: tried that, now both files got the reference to the cordova.js, jquery mobile and jquery normal, but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Once you add the xml files that @Coder_sLaY has mentioned, you need to add the server from where you are loading the jQuery Mobile JS file (the CDN URL) to the whitelist of allowed servers in cordova.xml